# Stripping an extension and directories from a string?

Tags: c, string

say I have the sring

`my/file/file.txt`

How would I go about stripping the slashes and the extension to just `file`? I have google'd my problem, and people have suggested `basename`, but I'm looking for something that would work on Windows too, any ideas?

Here's what I've tried:

```
char *rm_ext(char *file) {
    char *retstr;
    char *lastdot;
    if (file == NULL)
         return NULL;
    if ((retstr = malloc (strlen (file) + 1)) == NULL)
        return NULL;
    strcpy (retstr, file);
    lastdot = strrchr (retstr, '.');
    if (lastdot != NULL)
        *lastdot = '\0';
    return retstr;
}

char *get_file_name(char *path) {
    char *s = strrchr(path, '/');
    if (!s) return rm_ext(strdup(path));
    char *res = strdup(s + 1);
    char *res_no_ext = rm_ext(result);
    return res_no_ext;
}
```

It works, but not with `D:/` or double slashes, also I think it's giving me memory leaks since there's a bunch of hidden mallocs from strdup.

Comment: Windows complicates life...the backslash is also a pathname component separator, and you can have `D:` at the start to indicate a drive, not to mention special names like `NUL:`.  How much of that do you need?  For POSIX, [`basename()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/basename.html) is correct.  It won't deal with the extension.  Dealing with the basename is fiddly (`/` requires special handling, for example), but not very hard.  What have you tried?  Where are you having problems?

Comment: How about finding the last presence of a `/` and the only presence of a `.` and taking everything that is in between these positions?

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, take a look at the splitpath library function.
See [splitpath (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e737s6tf.aspx). For your case, pass NULL for 'drive', 'dir' and 'ext, since you don't need those parts.

Hope that helps.

Comment: So I could perhaps define that if on windows use splitpath, if on linux use basename?

Comment: @user3839220: That is certainly an option.  Define yourself a platform neutral interface to the functionality you want, and then implement it in different ways on POSIX and Windows.